# azure api management - facade for website

Tags: azure, rest, openapi, azure-api-management

We have an internal website that provides map data.

We'd like to make this data available to a 3rd party via http get requests, secured by oauth2.

I've created an openapi definition that corresponds to some of the high level website urls. I then imported this into apim and added a validate-jwt policy.

This works well. The 3rd party is able to obtain a jwt token from aad and get data from one of the apim operations that maps to a website page.

My question is, do I need to extend the openapi definition to include an api operation for each of the data "pages" that the 3rd party may need access to? I suspect there's an easier way and wondered if anyone can point me at an example?

Comment: In addition to just validating the jwt, don't you think you would need to enable "subscription required" in APIM for your API methods?

Comment: Most of the operations within the api need to be available to the public without any need for a subscription key